# weird devise/rails issue not sending username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have added username to a devise authentication setup, and for some reason, it's not inserting the username into the database. The database puts NULL in the username field.

I have included code for the migration, and the form, as well as the production log that shows that it sent the actual username.

Here is what I did:

So I added a migration to add a username, which was successful:

```
class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :username, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :username
  end
end
```

I then edited app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb to include a text field for username:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <p><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Here is the production log if that helps:

```
Started POST "/users" for 136.152.162.173 at Wed Feb 23 12:46:12 -0800 2011
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign up", "authenticity_token"=>"K8m6Em7IqSTFQG8aAYE4faUMsL2E46uNAllNTcsEF08=", "utf8"=>"?~\~S", "user"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "username"=>"pyramation", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"dan@email.com"}}
Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.1ms)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please you add your user model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added :username to your attr_accessible list in your User model? e.g.:

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username
```

Comment: That actually shouldn't matter, it's not required as the missing_method function handles those non-defined fields.

Comment: @nvez José Valim says it matters, and he's the author of Devise. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953945/rails-devise-signup-form-not-accepting-custom-username-field/3967546#3967546

Comment: Ahhh.. I see.. I have a model where it's working without it, but then again I do not have registration handled by devise so that could be why, my apologies good sir.

Comment: that was the fix. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad it was that simple. Happy coding!